# I have no way of click a "Pack" for my project library to publish it

Tags: visual-studio, publish

Can someone tell me how to do "Pack" on older project versions . I have two projects which are libraries, one shows the option "Pack" on the other I don't have this option.

[image]

[image]

Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, it turns out that the Core project allows you to pack this way.
The first project was SDK and the second was not.